# Full outer self join or something else

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
MID RID Name IsVisible
100 1   AA      1
100 2   AA      0
101 1   BB      1
101 2   BB      1
102 1   CC      0
102 2   CC      0 
103 1   DD      0
103 2   DD      1
```

How can i select distinct MID where IsVisible=0 in all RID.

Expected result is 102 which is IsVisible=0 for all RID.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: If you show the desired results from the sample data you gave, it'd be easier for us to understand what you're aiming for, because right now, it's a bit ambiguous.

Comment: `select distinct MID from t where IsVisible=0`

Comment: @Wanderer Please check the updated details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear, but perhaps this is what you want...?

Do a `GROUP BY`, check that both max and min IsVisible = 0.

```
select MID
from tablename
group by MID
having max(cast(IsVisible as int)) = 0
```

Comment: IsVisible is a Bit value

Comment: @Jkrish cast it to `int`

Comment: @Jkrish, then you can remove the `and min(IsVisible) = 0` part from the having clause. Now edited!

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS`

```
 select distinct t1.mid
 from your_table t1
 where not exists (
          select 1 
          from your_table t2 
          where t1.mid = t2.mid and t2.isVisible != 0
 )
```